# libvlc RTSP ip camera "libvlc demux: SETUP of'video/H264' failed 403 Forbidden" Qihan IP Camera Model:QH-NW357

Tags: xamarin, rtsp, libvlc, libvlcsharp

IP camera streams to PC via VLC RTP over RTSP, but cannot stream to android app via libvlc using Xamarin.Forms

1. I can stream the IP camera to my pc with VLC if I check the RTP over RTSP
2. My app can stream RTSP the BigBuckBunny example via libvlc
3. I can stream the IP camera with the VGX Android app

So I can stream the camera with different methods, but....
when I try to stream it with my app using libvlc I get the following log message

Thanks

Comment: 403 is the server telling you that you're not allowed to access the resource that you're requesting

Comment: We're gonna need more logs and a way to reproduce.

Comment: Hi MTZ - I've added more logs to the post

Comment: Problem solved for Xamarin.forms just put      _libvlc = new LibVLC("--rtsp-tcp"); in code

Comment: @Christoffel please post your solution to answer, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

MSFT

I've used this example from Martin Finkel -- https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/tree/master/VideoMosaic , for Xamarin.forms
All I've changed is line 19 in MainPage.xaml.cs from _libvlc = new LibVLC(); changed to
_libvlc = new LibVLC("--rtsp-tcp"); then I was able to stream "RTP over RTSP(TCP).
Hope it help

Comment: This answer will probably work for your specific model of camera. Can you edit your question to include its brand?